# Add legend to geom_line() graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I've been trying to add legend to my ggplot, but failed miserably.  I tried the function `scale_colour_manual()`, but the legend doesn't show up.

```
ggplot()+
geom_line(data=Summary,aes(y=Y1,x= X),colour="darkblue",size=1 )+
geom_line(data=Summary,aes(y=Y2,x= X),colour="red",size=1  )
```

My dataframe 'Summary' is as follows:

```
  X           Y1           Y2
139 1.465477e+16 7.173075e+15
277 1.044803e+16 9.275002e+15
415 1.059258e+16 8.562518e+15
553 1.033283e+16 8.268984e+15
691 9.548019e+15 1.022248e+16
830 1.008212e+16 8.641891e+15
968 9.822061e+15 9.315856e+15
1106 9.948143e+15 9.178694e+15
1244 1.013922e+16 8.825904e+15
1382 9.815094e+15 9.283662e+15
```

Please advise me how to plot Y1, Y2 against X on the same graph and add a legend on the side.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`ggplot` needs `aes` to make a legend, moving `colour` inside `aes(...)` will build a legend automatically. then we can adjust the labels-colors pairing via `scale_color_manual`:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=Summary,aes(y=Y1,x= X,colour="Y1"),size=1 )+
  geom_line(data=Summary,aes(y=Y2,x= X,colour="Y2"),size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Y series", values = c("Y1" = "darkblue", "Y2" = "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nathan, Thank you for your reply. Placing colour within the aes() works. I am not hopeful I would have figured it out by myself!

Comment: The problem is that colours provided in `aes()` has nothing in common with the displayed ones. You could set `colour='a'` and `coloud='b'` as well.

Comment: Nathan, thanks a lot! Searched for the tip to write it inside the aes for a while. *This* solved it!

Comment: This is not getting the intended effect. Y1 is supposed to be blue and Y2 is supposed to be red. Looking at the data, Y1 is greater than Y2 in all but one case, so the blue line should be mostly above the red line, but it's not.

Comment: This solution does not respect the colors you add in `aes()`

Comment: this is always so useful to look at

Answer (score 34):

As has been said, a color must be specified inside an aesthetic in order for there to be a legend. However, the color inside the aesthetic is actually just a label that then carries through to other layers. Setting custom colors can be done with `scale_color_manual` and the legend label can be fixed with `labs`.

```
ggplot(data=Summary)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=Y1,x= X,color="Y1"),size=1 ) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=Y2,x= X,color="Y2"),size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    'Y1' = 'darkblue',
    'Y2' = 'red')) +
  labs(color = 'Y series')
```

Answer (score 10):

To provide a more compact answer which only uses a single `geom` call:

`ggplot2` really likes long data (key-value pairs) better than wide (many columns).  This requires you to transform your data prior to plotting it using a package like `tidyr` or `reshape2`.  This way you can have a variable denoting color, inside your `aes` call, which will produce the legend.

For your data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- gather(data, variable, value, -x)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick", "dodgerblue"))
```

You can then customize the legend via `scale_color` series of helpers.

Comment: Although you mention that you can use scale_color, this answer does not provide reprex on how to create the legend.

Comment: @JessicaBurnett added the scale call