# Adding a legend to mixed ggplot after changing colors of lines in geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am having difficulty adding my legend back to my graph while using `geom_line()` command in R. Here is  some  reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(Sample = c("Mesa-6X", "Mesa-6X-Cen", "Mesa-600X", "Mesa-6000X", "Mesa-6X", "Mesa-6X-Cen", "Mesa-600X", "Mesa-6000X"), 
       CO2 = c("0.810", "0.630", "1.170", "0.882", "0.720", "0.377", "0.521", "0.444"), 
       Log = c(rep(1.68, 4), rep(2.2, 4)), 
       Colors = rep(c("tomato", "blue", "darkmagenta", "black"), 2))
```

There are multiple posts regarding this issue of legends not showing up such as: [Add legend to geom_line() graph in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833809/add-legend-to-geom-line-graph-in-r/40834306), [Reasons that ggplot2 legend does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768567/reasons-that-ggplot2-legend-does-not-appear) and quite a few others; however, none of the suggestions here or other tutorials I have searched seems to work on my code.

My objective: Change the color of the lines to the df$Colors while displaying the legend that shows the color that corresponds to the df$Sample column.

My code:
This code colors it fine, but the legend is missing and the `geom_point()` disappears.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df, 
            aes(x = Log, y = CO2), 
            size = 1.2, 
            color = df$Colors, 
            group = df$Sample) +
  geom_point(color = "black", 
             size = 1.2)
```

My code: 
This code adds a legend no problem, but it refuses to color it by the df$Colors column and it colors it by default instead - which is a rainbow type of color. Here, `geom_point()` works.  just fine. The graph I'm looking to make is this graph, but with the proper colors for the lines.

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = Log, 
           y = CO2, 
           color = df$Colors, 
           group = Sample)) + 
  geom_line(data = df, 
            aes(color = df$Sample), 
            size = 1.2) + 
  geom_point(color = "black", size = 1.2)
```

By the way: `class(df$Colors)` = factor

Thank you very much for your insights and help.

Comment: FYI you don't have to use `df$` inside `aes`

Comment: You should generally not use $ in aes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543753/4747043

Comment: `?scale_color_identity`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scale_color_manual`:

```
color_palette <-
  c("Mesa-6X" = "tomato", "Mesa-6X-Cen" = "blue", "Mesa-600X" = "darkmagenta", "Mesa-6000X" = "black")

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Log, y = CO2, color = Sample, group = Sample), size = 1.2) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = color_palette)
```

Comment: cardinal40: Thank you for the response; however, this code did not work. It made a graph, but all of the lines were black and there was no legend. Also, the `size = 1.2` didn't work. I even tried `scale_color_manual(values = df$Colors` to no avail.