# Create legend for line chart R GGPlot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello I am trying to add a legend to my graph:

[image]

Having looked at a few previous answers they all seem to rely on aes() or having the lines be related to a factor in some way. I didn't understand this answer [Add legend to geom_line() graph in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833809/add-legend-to-geom-line-graph-in-r).
In my case I simply want a legend that states "RED = No Cross Validation" and "BLUE = Cross Validation"

**R Code**

```
ggplot(data=graphDF,aes(x=rev(kAxis)))+
  geom_line(y=rev(noCVErr),color="red")+
  geom_point(y=rev(noCVErr),color="red")+
  geom_line(y=rev(CVErr),color="blue")+
  geom_point(y=rev(CVErr),color="blue")+
  ylim(minErr,maxErr)+
  ggtitle("The KNN Error Rate for Cross Validated and Non-Cross Validated Models")+
  labs(y="Error Rate", x = "1/K")
```

**Dataset**

```
   ks      kAxis   noCVAcc    noCVErr     CVAcc     CVErr
1   1 1.00000000 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.8279075 0.1720925
2   3 0.33333333 0.9345238 0.06547619 0.8336898 0.1663102
3   5 0.20000000 0.8809524 0.11904762 0.8158645 0.1841355
4   7 0.14285714 0.8690476 0.13095238 0.8272727 0.1727273
5   9 0.11111111 0.8809524 0.11904762 0.7857398 0.2142602
6  11 0.09090909 0.8809524 0.11904762 0.7500891 0.2499109
7  13 0.07692308 0.8511905 0.14880952 0.7622103 0.2377897
8  15 0.06666667 0.7976190 0.20238095 0.7320856 0.2679144
9  17 0.05882353 0.7916667 0.20833333 0.7320856 0.2679144
10 19 0.05263158 0.7559524 0.24404762 0.7201426 0.2798574
11 21 0.04761905 0.7678571 0.23214286 0.7023173 0.2976827
12 23 0.04347826 0.7440476 0.25595238 0.6903743 0.3096257
13 25 0.04000000 0.7559524 0.24404762 0.6786096 0.3213904
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you put your data into "long" form, such as this for your data frame `graphDF` (perhaps using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` if necessary):

```
library(tidyr)

graphDF_long <- pivot_longer(data = graphDF, 
                             cols = c(noCVErr, CVErr), 
                             names_to = "model", 
                             values_to = "errRate")
```

This creates a new data.frame called `graphDF_long` that has a single column for the error rate, and a new column that specifies model:

```
      ks kAxis noCVAcc CVAcc model   errRate
   <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1 1       1     0.828 noCVErr  0     
 2     1 1       1     0.828 CVErr    0.172 
 3     3 0.333   0.935 0.834 noCVErr  0.0655
 4     3 0.333   0.935 0.834 CVErr    0.166 
 5     5 0.2     0.881 0.816 noCVErr  0.119 
 6     5 0.2     0.881 0.816 CVErr    0.184 
 ....
```

Then, you can simplify your `ggplot` statement, and use an aesthetic with the column `model` for color:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = graphDF_long, aes(x = rev(kAxis), y = rev(errRate), color = model)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), 
                     labels = c("Cross Validation", "No Cross Validation")) +
  ylim(min(graphDF_long$errRate), max(graphDF_long$errRate)) +
  ggtitle("The KNN Error Rate for Cross Validated and Non-Cross Validated Models") +
  labs(y="Error Rate", x = "1/K")
```

This will generate the legend automatically:

[image: plot with legend]

Comment: Could you add to your answer how you would convert the dataset to "long" form as I am unfamiliar. I have added the dataset to the question.  noCVErr and CVErr is what is plotted.

Comment: Please see edited answer that shows how you can put your data into "long" format. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks thats great!